# How to add permissions I have to another user in Drupal 8?

Tags: 8, users

I have two roles, editor and employee. "A" user is in editor role and can change permissions, for example he can add users to employee role or remove them. However, it would be good that users in editor role can change permissions but only ones that they have.

Use case: "A" user in editor role can add member into editor role but cannot remove any members from administrator role because "A" user is not in that role.

How can I reach this above?

Comment: "it would be good that users in editor role can change permissions but only ones that they have." is confusing and contradictory to the Use case. Given the use case, [Administer Users by Role](https://www.drupal.org/project/administerusersbyrole) is the contributed module that allows an user to only modify users (including roles) of a configured role.